# Did the Potter parents have a will/a testament? Who was supposed to raise Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that wizards know of a last will and testament. After Sirius dies, Dumbledore tells Harry:

> “I must tell you that Sirius’s will was discovered a week ago and that he left you everything he owned.” (HBP)

So did Harry's parents have a will?

- If they did, what was the content? Especially what did it say about Harry?
- If they didn't, why not?

---

It's funny (or not) how all the comments and the only answer so far are limited to how the money got to Harry.

We know that Sirius inherited everything from his parents, including Grimmauld Place and Kreacher, just because he was the only surviving son. The dislike between Sirius and his parents was mutual. Sirius ran away when he was 16, his mother Walburga blasted his name of the family tree. So it doesn't seem likely that his parents would actively do something for him to inherit. Just the fact that he was the only remaining son after Regulus died was enough. As Harry's parents loved him, there is no reason to assume that they would not leave their money to Harry.

It has been tradition since long before there were written laws that the possessions of the deceased would go to the children unless specified otherwise, because that is what most parents would want. Details can vary, either equal split, everything to the oldest, or something in between, but in the case of on only (surviving) child like Harry or Sirius, this doesn't matter.

The main point is, what were the wishes of the Potter parents regarding Harry's guardians. Sirius was Harry's godfather, but he was also pretending to be the secret keeper, a dangerous job in an already dangerous time. So it was not certain that he would be available or alive to raise Harry. They should have made further plans.

Comment: Considering Harry's large inheritance of money, they must've had SOME kind of will.

Comment: @Allball103 - Not really needed. Harry was their only son and any of their friends (not least Dumbledore, a man of impeccable standing) could have attested to the fact that they wanted to leave it all to him.

Comment: It would've been somewhat irresponsible of them being members of the order of the phoenix, at constant risk of death, to not have a will.

Comment: @Allball103 The UK has statutes that deal with people who die "[intestate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intestacy)" (without a will). According to WP, the gist of the law there is that if there's one kid and no surviving spouse, the kid gets it all.

Comment: @Cadence - except that - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110040/do-british-muggle-laws-apply-to-the-british-wizarding-world

Comment: @NKCampbell The principles of intestacy are well-established parts of the common law. Absent any reason to think the wizards *don't* have a similar principle, I would assume they do, just like I assume they have a law against theft even if it isn't stated. The exact statute may well be different, but this isn't a particularly controversial case as far as intestacy goes.

Comment: sure - just saying that citing UK law isn't necessarily authoritative :)

Comment: @NKCampbell Only children inheriting their parents’ estates outright is not just UK law, though—it’s pretty much ubiquitous in the Western World and has been since long before laws were codified. The wizarding community clearly have their own codified laws, but given that they probably did not start being codified sooner than Muggle laws, there’s no reason to suspect that they’re not based on the same premises where these premises apply equally well to both communities.

Comment: Totally non-canonical, a *really* common bit of fanon is that Dumbledore kept the wills from being discovered or read whether it's to gain control of Harry's money or to ensure he stays with the Dursleys for one reason or another.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I know, but the question here is whether there are established canon facts about the will or whether Rowling said something about the subject.

Comment: they probably didn't expect to die.

Comment: @ava While most people don't **expect** to die, most also realize that it can happen, even without a civil war and being the explicit target of a dark lord. Especially parents should have plans for the care of their children.

Comment: A will is not the only way to distribute your property when you die. Other common will alternatives include intestacy, nonprobate assets, revocable living trusts, and community property agreements.

Answer (score 11):

## It’s not clear - but Harry did inherit what seems like everything.

Whether or not they had an official will, somehow the Potters’ money was considered left to Harry. Hagrid tells Harry that his parents left him money, but whether it was specified as Harry’s in a will isn’t mentioned, just that Harry’s inherited his parents’ money (somehow).

> “I haven’t got any money – and you heard Uncle Vernon last night – he won’t pay for me to go and learn magic.’
>
> ‘Don’t worry about that,’ said Hagrid, standing up and scratching his head. ‘D’yeh think yer parents didn’t leave yeh anything?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 5 (Diagon Alley)*</sup></sub>

It’s not specified *how* the money is left to Harry - they may have left a will or they may not have. If they did, even if Hagrid knew about it, he probably didn’t consider it useful to tell Harry (who was a kid) the legalities of the situation. Even if there wasn’t any will, it’s very likely that others (most likely Dumbledore) would step in to make sure Harry would inherit his parents’ money. It would be a fairly clear cut case. There wasn’t really anyone else who could claim the right to the Potter wealth. Other than Petunia, Lily’s Muggle sister, the rest of Harry’s close family were all dead.

> MA: What about Harry's family — his grandparents — were they killed?
>
> JKR: No. This takes us into more mundane territory. As a writer, it was more interesting, plot-wise, if Harry was completely alone. So I rather ruthlessly disposed of his entire family apart from Aunt Petunia. I mean, James and Lily are massively important to the plot, of course, but the grandparents? No. And, because I do like my backstory: Petunia and Lily's parents, normal Muggle death. James's parents were elderly, were getting on a little when he was born, which explains the only child, very pampered, had-him-late-in-life-so-he's-an-extra-treasure, as often happens, I think. They were old in wizarding terms, and they died. They succumbed to a wizarding illness. That's as far as it goes. There's nothing serious or sinister about those deaths. I just needed them out of the way so I killed them. 
> <sub><sup>*[- The Leaky Cauldron (July 16, 2005)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-3.htm)*</sup></sub>

Harry was the sole survivor, and the Boy who Lived, so it’s unlikely that anyone would be able to claim the money wasn’t rightfully his. Hagrid had the key to the Potters’ vault at Gringotts, so it seems likely that it, and the vault, were being kept safe and ‘held’ for Harry.

Comment: I never thought about this before, but if Harry did actually inherit everything, which seems the _a priori_ conclusion, then when he and Hermione visited Godric’s Hollow in _DH_, **the ruin of the old Potter house was actually his**. He was basically a young real estate tycoon, already with two prime properties under his belt!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - One is a ruin, the other is invisible. Even 'Homes Under the Hammer' would struggle to say nice things about them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet A ruin of a modest house doesn't make him a real estate tycoon. But who should inherit if not Harry? My question is more about what arrangements were made for Harry's upbringing, not whether or not he would inherit his parents properties.

Comment: @Valorum I’m sure they’d manage. If nothing else, the Black house was a huge, seemingly detached house _in London_. I’m sure it could be made un-invisible again, in which case it’d be worth a fortune, even with all the anti-everything spells!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Hmm. I guess you could argue that the invisibility is a feature rather than a flaw. Now if it also had invisible *off-street parking* it'd be worth millions.

Comment: @Valorum “Tired of nosy neighbours? Can’t seem to find privacy in your own home? Try the all-new invisible house and you’ll never have to worry about neighbours again!”

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - But imagine having to explain to your wife that you just paid £1.4M for an uptown house but that you ***seem to have mislaid it...***

Comment: @Valorum Such are the risks of real estate hunting in London. One must take a few chances here and there!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's assuming the Potters owned the house in Godric's Hollow. It's likely, considering that James Potter was incredibly rich due to the inheritance from his parents, but they may also have not placed the Fidelius charm on their own house.

Comment: It begs the question whether the Potters were freehold or leasehold on their invisible property.

Comment: @QuestionAuthority he was supposed to go to Sirius since he was his godfather

Comment: @Jungkook If this is supposed to be an answer, why is the comment attached to an answer and not to the question?

Comment: The Fidelius Charm could probably have simply been undone by posting the address in the Daily Prophet when putting the Black property up for sale. As long as Harry or another secret keeper wrote it down, it could probably be published (or an image of it could be posted). Then probably every witch or wizard in Great Britain would've been in on the secret and been able to see it. Fidelius charms can likely be ended willingly, too, though, by agreement of all living secret keepers.

Answer (score 1):

### We don't know for sure.

There's two paths this could take.

1. They did not, because they weren't expecting to die at such a young age.
2. They realized they were in the middle of all out warfare and writing a Will was recommended.

Let's choose path one first. They didn't write a will, and assumed that if they passed that baby Harry would live with Sirius. (Not Lupin, who they suspected to be the spy.) They also probably assumed the house would be left to Sirius to live in until Harry came of age to take ownership. Remember, they probably thought if they were to die, it **would not be directly at their home, but probably on a mission somewhere.** They also probably thought one of them would die if it came to it, not both. If one passed, obviously all ownership would belong to the surviving.

But anyway, if they didn't write a will, all ownership belongs to Harry and would be kept by Sirius until Harry came of age.

Path 2: Probably something similar. Again, they weren't expected to BOTH pass away, they didn't expect to die at their home, and they didn't expect for Sirius to be taken to jail. So, they probably would have left their house and money to baby Harry, to live in with Sirius until Harry turns seventeen and can take ownership for himself.

So, probably the same goes for both!

Final answer is there's nothing in canon, so we don't actually know.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it simple?

Sirius's will was discovered because Grimmauld Place was searched. Before vacating the HQ of the Order, it was searched and the will was discovered. The will was not given to someone for safekeeping because Sirius didn't honestly plan on dying.

Reg the Potter's will, well it is obvious that their money went to their son. However, there was no will because Lily and James trusted Pettigrew. Further, they knew that if anything happened to them, the other Marauders wouldn't let Harry be penniless. They would take care of him.
Also, I guess it would be Lily who had second thoughts and left the key to the Gringotts vault with Dumbledore - for just in case scenarios. Or probably so that Dumbledore could help them with the items of need since they were in hiding. So probably Dumbledore would give money to Pettigrew who would buy and take goods to them. Or simply Lily had one of those intuitions and wanted to ensure that the key reached the rightful owner.

I doubt if a will is required for this - I mean what if the Potters had already transferred the ownership to their son? Or since the old wizarding families own accounts in the bank, the ownership gets passed on to the successor who possesses the key. Here Harry was the only descendent and he got the key!

Comment: This sounds like speculation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with speculation, as long as it is aligned with common sense. But most of the speculation here is baseless. A comment is too short to address all points, I would need an answer for that. Additionally, everybody here agrees that a will is not necessary to leave properties to Harry. A will is necessary regarding Harry's guardian, and I already had the question amended by the time you posted this answer.

Comment: I never mentioned that there was any will! Even I am agreeing to it. Reg Harry's guardian.. Sirius was made the godfather when Harry was born.. and then because Sirius, James and Lily - all were unavailable, Dumbledore took charge to place Harry where he was most safe.